# My d3.js Scales are not working

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, scale

I am new to d3.js and is currently making a simple bar chart in version 4. I understand the basic idea of a scale. The problem is whenever I reload my page, some of my bars on my bar chart are cut in half, or is moved all the way to the top(or bottom) this is my code. I want my bars to stay within the svg but if i were to put for example

```
.attr(height, function(d){ return yScale(d)]);
```

It wont work. Any ideas? my code should be located on the bottom.

```
var data = [ 40,60,80,100,600,700];
var height = 500, width = 500;  


var canvas  = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height",height);


var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
           .domain([40, 700])
           .range([0,400]);


var bars = canvas.selectAll("rect")
             .data(data)
             .enter()
             .append("rect")
                .attr("width", 30)
                .attr("height", function(d){ return   yScale(d)})

                .attr("x", function(d,i){ return i * 35})
                .attr("y", function(d) { return height - d});



}
```

Output of image is here.

[image]

Comment: The code you provided has a syntax error.  Did you mean } instead of ]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is this line:

```
.attr("y", function(d) {
    return height - d
});
```

Why are you using the raw data value? You have to use the value returned by the scale:

```
.attr("y", function(d) {
    return height - yScale(d)
});
```

Here is the updated code:

```js
var data = [40, 60, 80, 100, 600, 700];
var height = 500,
  width = 500;

var canvas = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([40, 700])
  .range([0, 400]);

var bars = canvas.selectAll("rect")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("width", 30)
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return yScale(d)
  })
  .attr("x", function(d, i) {
    return i * 35
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return height - yScale(d)
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```